# How can I configure thunderbird 3 to show each folder in its own tab?

Tags: tabs, thunderbird

In thunderbird 3, I can open new tabs if I middle-click, but the behaviour I want is for left-click to open a new tab if there is not already a folder open for a given tab; or to switch to the tab displaying that folder if there is.

Is there a configuration setting or addon which will make thunderbird behave like that?

Answer (score 1):

It's not precisely what you want but have a look at [Quickfolders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quickfolders-tabbed-folders/) add-on

Quickfolders is a tool which allows you to bookmark folders onto a new toolbar. You can then drag mail to that folder icon on the toolbar, and also click the icon to go directly to that folder - all without scrolling around or searching.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. In this case, perhaps you could add a short description of this addon?

Comment: > in this case, perhaps you could add a short description of this addon?

@Nathan.Eilisha Shiraini I hope I have addressed this concern

Answer (score 0):

From [Thunderbird 3 Features](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/features/) :

> Right-clicking on messages or folders
>   will open them in a tab in the
>   background.

Comment: OK... but how do I get them to open with a left-click, and how do I get them to be one per folder?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that with a left-click.